# Transform Array to list of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I use angular cli 6.

How can i transform this first array to the second array ?

```
[Array(4)]
 0:(2) ["a", "b"]


 (2) ["a", "b"]
    0:"a"
    1:"b"
```

I try this :

```
   var newArr = [...this.ppssToDisplay.effetsind[0]];
 console.log(this.ppssToDisplay.effetsind) ;
 console.log(newArr) ;
 this.ppsForm.controls['requirements'].setValue(newArr);
```

I obtain :

```
console.log(this.ppssToDisplay.effetsind) ;

[Array(1)]
0:Array(1)
0:(2) ["Troubles de la vessie", "Troubles de l'érection"]
length:1


console.log(newarr) ;
  [Array(2)]0: Array(2)0: "Troubles de la vessie"1: "Troubles de l'érection"length: 2__proto__: Array(0)length: 1__proto__: Array(0)
```

But i need this kind of array :
(2) ["a", "b"]
        0:"a"
        1:"b"

Comment: First one is 2 dimensional array i.e. array of arrays. To get the first value you can simply use array[0]

Comment: The first Array really doesn't have anything in common with the second Array, it's really hard to tell how you want the first array transformed

Comment: Please update your question: What is difference between arrays is not really specific. I see multiple formats for your arrays, could you change that? And lastly this question has not really to do anything with Angular (CLI), perhaps it might be better to leave that out. Please refer to: [How to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I updated my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first array seems to be something like `[["a", "b"],,,,]` , probably a sparse array, but we are sure that the first position is another array (dense) made of 2 elements. To transform that into `["a", "b"]` you could use [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
var arr = [["a", "b"],,,,];

var newArr = [...arr[0]]

console.log(newArr)
```

in your code: `newArr = [...this.ppssToDisplay.effetsind[0]];`

Comment: I obtain this : 
[Array(2)]
0:(2) ["Troubles de la vessie", "Troubles de l'érection"]
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)

Comment: and to this. ppssToDisplay i have : [Array(1)]
0
:
Array(1)
0
:
(2) ["Troubles de la vessie", "Troubles de l'érection"]

Comment: It's hard doctor ?

Comment: @Emmeus lol now newA =" T" but console.log(this.ppsToDisplay.effetsind) say : (2) ["Troubles de la vessie", "Troubles de l'érection"]

Comment: @Newbiiiie I'm confused now this.ppsToDisplay.effetsind then is the right